# Python3 extensions - working with files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-extensions

I am working on a Python extension module in C++ and I have a `FILE` object and I want to propagate it Python code so I can work in some way (reading, writing, etc). In Python2 it was possible to use `PyFile_FromFile` and create a Python object. Since this is deprecated in Python3, What is a best way now?

Comment: like `object = open('myfile.txt', 'r')`?

Comment: @Kamejoin, I should emphasized that I am writing a C++ (Python extension) module.